# How to determine what direction an object should orbit around another

Tags: unity, 2d, vector, hinge-joint

I am creating a game in Unity with 2D. When a button is clicked a static object is attaching a hinge joint to a dynamic object, so the dynamic object orbits it. When the dynamic object gets attached, I am setting the dynamics objects `transform.up` vector to be pointing at the static object. Then, taking what ever the dynamic objects magnitude was and setting that as its velocity to the right. I do this because I want the dynamic object to orbit the planet at the same exact speed as when it wasn't orbiting.

The problem I am having, is I don't know how to determine if the object should orbit clockwise or counter-clockwise. It's easy for me to determine this when I look at an image, but I don't know how to via code.

Here is an example
[image]

Does anyone know how I can determine this?

Comment: Off-hand guess: compare the angle made by the arrow in your image (is that the original velocity vector?) with the line between the two object's centers. That angle will either have a positive value or a negative value, which will be your CW or CCW.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Welcome to the joy of the cross product!

The cross product of two 3D vectors gives a third vector that's perpendicular to both the inputs:

```
Vector3 c = Vector3.Cross(a, b);
```

In a left-handed coordinate system like Unity's, you can make a thumbs-up pose with your left hand, and hold it so that the flat of your hand points in the direction `a` and your fingers curl toward `b`. The cross product of the two points in the direction of your thumb.

That means if `a` and `b` are in the 2D plane `xy`, the cross product points along the `z` axis: with `z` component greater than zero if `b` is clockwise of `a`, and less than zero if `b` is counter-clockwise of `a`.

So, specifically:

```
float OrbitDirection(Rigidbody2D orbiter, Transform center) {
    Vector3 toCenter = center.position - orbiter.position;
    return Mathf.Sign(Vector3.Cross(orbiter.velocity, toCenter).z);
    // This is equivalent to:
    // return Mathf.Sign(orbiter.velocity.x * toCenter.y - orbiter.velocity.y * toCenter.x);
}
```

This returns `+1.0f` if the object should orbit counter-clockwise (positive rotation about the z axis), and `-1.0f` if the object should orbit clockwise (negative rotation about the z axis).